# window.location not working

Tags: apex, javascript

I am stuck in a situation, hope so I could get some help here.

I'm having a condition where I want to redirect a page to one URL. It is related to service cloud console.

In controller I defined a merge variable :

```
public string finalURL {get; set;}
```

VF page :

```
<apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save" onComplete="refreshTab({!isError});"/>
```

and I am using this memebr variable in Javascript.

Javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

           function refreshTab(isError) {
               if (!isError) {
                   sforce.console.getEnclosingPrimaryTabId(refreshTabById);
               }
           }
           function refreshTabById(tabId) {
               if(sforce && sforce.console && sforce.console.isInConsole()) {
                   sforce.console.refreshPrimaryTabById(tabId.id, true);
               } else {
                   var urlString = {!finalURL}; //'https://cs14.salesforce.com/1234'
                   window.location = urlString;
               }
           }      

       </script>
```

But, the issue is, when code is coming to the else condition, the page is not redirecting to the new URL defined. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

**Your custom button code is throwing a JavaScript exception.**

This is because `{!finalURL}` will dump an unescaped URL out into the middle of your source code - you will want to put quotes `''` around him like so, and escape for good measure also:

```
var urlString = '{!JSENCODE(finalURL)}'; //https://cs14.salesforce.com/1234
window.location.href = urlString;
```

(Regal has a good point too: `window.location` will still work, but it's better practise to use `href`)

Answer (score 3):

You should use: `window.location.href` instead of `window.location`.

- `window.location` is an object you shouldn't assign a `string` to object.
- `window.location.href` is a property that tells you the current URL location of the browser.

> ```
>  window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'; //Will redirect you to Google immediately.
> ```

Comment: This doesn't correctly answer the question. Replacing `window.location` with `window.location.href` does **not** fix the problem.

Comment: The other issue is that the first bullet point is wrong. Technically, `window.location` is not an object, but a [property with getter and setter methods](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#the-location-interface). The getter returns the [*Location*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)  object associated with the window's document, whilst the setter is effectively an [alias](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) to the `window.location.href` property…

Comment: … You are not actually assigning a string to an object but setting a property to a string. A subsequent fetch of the `location` property will still return a *Location* object, albeit now with a different `href` property. It works this way for historical reasons. Maybe you could say that you shouldn't use this form as it **looks** like you are assigning a string to an object property.